# How to save images from Wordpress in Flutter

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, dart

I am trying to save images from Wordpress to my Flutter app. I am using this code but it doesn’t save any images:

```
List<CachedNetworkImage> posts;

   Future<String> getPosts() async {

    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl + "posts?_embed"), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      for(int i = 0; i < res.body.length; i++ ) {
        posts.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl:
          resBody[i]["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"],
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),));
                }
    setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      posts = resBody;
      print(posts);
    });

    return "Success!";
  }
```

I want to save the images to a list. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but here is what I tried and got the list of images from the WP site to show in the app, see the result [here](https://prnt.sc/1u0m2k3):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<List<String>> _lst;
  
  // getting the list of urls for images
  Future<List<String>> getImages() async {
    List<String> _result = [];

    var _url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed';
    var _resp = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url));
    var _json = jsonDecode(_resp.body);

    for (var element in _json) {
      // on the site I was testing with not all posts had
      // wp:featuredmedia
      var _e = element['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'];
      if (_e != null) {
        _result.add(_e[0]['source_url']);
      }
    }

    return _result;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _lst = getImages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _lst,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: (snapshot.data!)[index],
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```